# how to fix 403: forbidden in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have created an application using Asp.net, C#, Sql Server, javascript. Its quite simple application. But, I am facing a strange issue after deployment in the UAT and Production server.

**Problem:**
I am searching list of candidates using the "location", for e.g. - Pune / Bangalore / Kolkata.
Now, When I am searching by any location except "Bangalore", its fetching the records and displaying in the gridview. But, if I search by "Bangalore", its showing no records.
I used the "google chrome Developer tools" and also "firebug in firefox", and its showing:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) --- http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/es/frmPeople.aspx
```

and

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 403 --- ScriptResource.axd:939
```

I cannot be able to understand why this is happening only for "Bangalore" and not for other locations?
Secondly, what does this error means exactly?

Please help guys...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you enable the developer toolbar (F12 in IE), and turn on Network profiling, does it tell you which resources it can get (200) and which are forbidden (403)?

Comment: I mentioned the files which are showing as 403: forbidden. That is: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/es/frmPeople.aspx and ScriptResource.axd:939

Comment: If you paste that link into a new tab of your browser, do you get an error? Are you using any Response.Redirects in your application, and are they all pointing to the correct places?

Comment: Yeah, response.redirects have been used throughout the application. But, my point is that why this forbidden error only for a particular location? I mean, if I search candidates by "Kolkata" or "Pune" or "Chennai" or "Mumbai", its fetching the records and showing them in the grid but while searching by "bangalore" location, its giving this error. Now, if response.redirects was the problem then it would have happened for all the locations, isn't it? Secondly, what is this "ScriptResource.axd" file, I never added such file in my application?

Comment: There are resources that you are directing the browser to that have a permissions issue. It could be error related (hence the "bangalore" only result) where it may be an error image/script, or the result of a named resource (image/file/page/etc associated with Bangalore). The ScriptResource.axd serves dynamic scripts for asp.net pages (the postbacks and page validations mostly).

Comment: Also, If you have a global.asax, and you can enable the remote debugging tools for one of the problem servers (UAT), you can attach Visual Studio to the site and catch any error in the Application_Error method of the global.asax.

Comment: Ok. I will try debugging the global.asax file. By the way, can this problem be occurred due to record size? I mean, in bangalore the number of records are "7043" and in other locations, the records are much less than that. So, I was thinking that it might be due to the number of records.

Comment: It could its causing a redirect to a custom error page, or other resource (paging icons, or something like that) that is restricted.

Comment: If you cant get the debugging tools installed or working, and you are able to make code changes and redeploy, you can put logging code in your application_error method.